# ASP MVC - how to separate tables (received from stored procedure) using table names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I used to get multiple tables (in my old aspx project) returned from a single stored procedure, by getting the dataset into a DataSet ds, like

`DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables["tabe_name1"];
DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables["tabe_name2"]`

I can get the table using a model if only one table is returned, using function

`con.Query<ModelName>("STORED_PROCEDURE", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

How can I do this in MVC using Dapper ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get multiple grids you must use:

```
using(var multi = conn.QueryMultiple(...)) {
    // see below
}
```

Inside the "see below", you can access each grid *in turn*, once only - they are not named. For example:

```
using(...) {
    var orders = multi.Read<Order>().AsList();
    var custs = multi.Read<Customer>().AsList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marc, these also worked for me while I tried your answer.

`var orders = multi.Read<Order>().Single<Order>();
var orders = multi.Read<Order>().ToList<Order>();
var orders = multi.Read<string>().Single<string>();`
//this third one worked as if calling ExecuteScalar in aspx projects, ie., to get value of cell (0,0) only.